# Increase height of an object

Tags: vertices

I want to increase the height of a cylinder object used to support a microcontroller (ESP32 Devkit).

From:
[image]

To:
[image]

However the scale or transform tool behaving strange with the object. Explained in gif https://media.giphy.com/media/9O9DV6aPSzA1fZ6Fz2/giphy.gif, tools increasing height from bottom of the base.

I've tried selecting only outer circle of thicker part but it doesn't help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't select the bottom vertices?

Comment: What moonboots says in short is, if you select the vertices that are connected to the bottom, of course the bottom will move up, too... since it's connected it has to follow otherwise the cylinder would move up and there would be a gap between it and the bottom.

Comment: What the others say!  The easiest way is to go into face select mode (normal '3' key), select the top face of the pillar and then use Ctrl  Numpad+ to select the area you need to raise. Then use G Z to move it up.

Comment: It's the same answer as in your last question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go into Edit Mode
2. Enter Wireframe View mode
3. select the top vertices of the cylinders[image]

4. Press "G," then "Z"
5. Move the mouse up to change the height of the cylinder
6. Exit Edit Mode

Done!